# Insert/update values into multiple tables - laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Just started laravel few days ago.

I have a simple form

```
<form action="/download" method="POST">
@csrf
<input type="hidden" name="unique_key" value="{{$template->unique_key}}">
<button>Download</button>
</form>
```

How am I able to pass $_POST values into controller and then make a logic by inserting data into multiple tables.
To be more clear I made in procedular php what I want to achieve
(!!!content below is just for explaining!!!)

```
$user_id = $_SESSION['user_id'];
$unique_key= $_POST['unique_key'];

$sql = "SELECT * FROM template WHERE unique_key= $unique_key";
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
$product_id = $row['id'];
$product_name = $row['product_name'];

$sql2 = "UPDATE 'users' SET downloads = downloads + 1 WHERE id = $user_id";

$sql3 = "INSERT INTO downloads ('user_id', 'product_id') VALUES('$user_id', '$product_id')";

 header('Content-type: application/pdf');
  header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$product_name.'.pdf"');
```

My table structure

```
       USERS            TEMPLATE                                DOWNLOADS
|----------------| |---------------------------------| |---------------------------|
| id | downloads | |  id | unique_key | product_name | | id | user_id | product_id |
|    |           | |     |            |              | |    |         |            |
|    |           | |     |            |              | |    |         |            |
|----------------| |---------------------------------| |---------------------------|
```

I have UserController(User model) & TemplateController(Template model). Probably I need to make downloads controller to access downloads mysql table ? But anyway, how am I able to insert from one table to another, at this moment I stuck with blank function

```
    public function download(Request $request, User $user, Template $template){
        
    }
```

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/controllers